# ngx-bootstrap datepicker only 50% visible

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

I want to add bootstarp-datepicker to my page (working in angular), I just simply followed the instructions from: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker , It seems working until i open the date picker, cause only the 50% of it is visible, however I didn't add extra styling code to it.

Here is the import:

```
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform- 
browser/animations';
.
.
.
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserAnimationsModule
    ...      
  ]
 })
```

And the Html file:

```
<div class="DatePicker1">
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Datepicker"
           class="form-control"
           bsDatepicker>
  </div>
```

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIigU.png)

Comment: Looks like an issue with your styling, could you post all your code to codepen or jsbin along with the css for DatePicker1?

Comment: DatePicker1 have no css,  I just added only this code ... and it's doint this, seems working because how it look is like bootstrap datepicker shoud, only a bit slipped

Comment: I think it has conflict with your global css. And your field is too small. Add wider width maybe